# What command can I use to extract fields from this Git svn mirror commit messages?

Tags: git, parsing, svn, text-extraction, utilities

The text below is a commit message comes from a Git mirror of a live Subversion and all the commit messages are in this style. Is there some command I can use to extract the information in a table like manner, a sigle line per commit.

```
commit c49a28ae19400fd14d60cd42fda9b3f527a5ee80
Author: martin <martin@4005530d-fff6-0310-9dd1-cebe43e6787f>
Date:   Mon Mar 23 00:45:30 2015 +0000

    SynEdit: win, IME Handler: Fixed (added) overwrite selection. Issue 0027712

    git-svn-id: http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk@48459 4005530d-fff6-0310-9dd1-cebe43e6787f
```

In this instance the output would be like

```
date, git-commit, svn-commit, author, note
Mon Mar 23 00:45:30 2015 +0000, c49a28ae1, 48459, martin@xxxxx, SynEdit, etc
```

and so on.
I have tried using some commands like

```
# get the commit id of the nth revision
git log -n 1 | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2
```

and

```
# get svn id of HEAD revision
git log -n 1 | head -n 7 | tail -n 1 | cut -d "@" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

It is getting rather awkward and hairy and I am looking for a better tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
git log --format=format:"%ad,%h,,%ae,%s" <other selection parameters>
```

except that doesn't include the svn id (and I'm not sure if the date and email formats are what you want). Presumably the svn id can be extracted from the full commit note, so you should be able to use a format like

```
--format=format:"%ad,%h,,%ae,%s%n%N"
```

and pass it through an `gawk` script something like:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,out,/,/);next;}
     match($0,/@[0-9]+/){out[3]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}
     END{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",out[1],out[2],out[3],out[4],out[5]}'
```

None of this is tested. :)